# How to display date in Page Layout in specific format

Tags: 2013, page-layout, publishing-page, date-time

I am using the following code to display date in a publishing page layout.

```
<SharePointWebControls:FieldValue runat="server" FieldName="Created" id="CreatedOn"/>
```

This displays both date & time and I only want to display date and not time.
Secondly it displays date in format

> mm/d/yyyy

and I want it in format

> month_name dd, yyyy

For e.g. December 04, 2013

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably many people would say to use the `DateTimeField` and set `DateOnly="True"`, like this:

```
<SharePointWebControls:DateTimeField runat="server" DateOnly="true" FieldName="Created" id="CreatedOn"/>
```

But that tends to create problems and throws errors.

What I would do is to use inline code:

```
<%=SPContext.Current.ListItem["Created"] != null? (new DateTime(SPContext.Current.ListItem["Created"].ToString()).ToString("USE FORMAT DATE STRING HERE"): string.Empty %>
```

I have not tried the above codes solidity, but it should give you an idea of how to use it.

More on the `DateTime.ToString(string)` here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Can I use the above code in Page Layout in SharePoint designer?

Comment: In a page layout it should be OK, but why not just update the Page Layout in your solution and update it?

Comment: You mean I should open it in Visual Studio and then edit?

Comment: That would be the persistant approach

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something similar to Aakash, but also added a check as to not break edit mode.

```
<div id="my-change-date" class="my-date-line">..</div>
<script>
   $(function () {
   var date = new Date($("#my-change-date").text());
   if (date instanceof Date && !isNaN(date.valueOf())) {
   $("#my-change-date").text(date.format("M/d/yyyy"));
   }
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `DateOnly="true"` throw error.
So, you can replace value by script like this:

wrap the field

```
<span class="myDate">
    <SharePointWebControls:FieldValue runat="server" FieldName="Created" id="CreatedOn"/>
</span>
```

set value by js :

```
    if($('.myDate').text() != ""){
       var date = $('.myDate').text().split(' ')[0].split('/')
       var formatDate = new Date(date[2],date[1]-1,date[0])    
       $('.myDate').text(formatDate.format("MMM dd,yyyy"))
    }
```