# SPDesigner - pageLayOut aspx file

Tags: sharepoint-designer, page-layout

Hello I want to get only date and month in pagelayout. I edin aspx file.

**This is my code:**

```
<div class="event-date">
<span>  
    <%@ SPContext.Current.ListItem["SODigitalPageDate"] != null? (new DateTime(SPContext.Current.ListItem["SODigitalPageDate"].toString()).ToString("s") %>
 </span>  
</div>
```

**This is following error error:**

> /_catalogs/masterpage/NewsPageLayout.aspx. The server block is not well formed.

I checked this question [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/84318/how-to-display-date-in-page-layout-in-specific-format)

Answer (score 2):

So take a look at my answer in the question you link to:

You are using

```
<%@
```

to open the code block, the answer uses

```
<%=
```

You are also missing the `: string.Empty` part in the end of the line

So

```
<%= SPContext.Current.ListItem["SODigitalPageDate"] != null ? (new DateTime(SPContext.Current.ListItem["SODigitalPageDate"].ToString()).ToString("s") : string.Empty %>
```